# Best way to test search results non personalized results

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

When testing my ranking for specific keywords and search appearance I usually open a chrome incognito and perform a search. But, it seems this doesn't work as I expect, and other people see results differently, if they do the same.

Why is this? What's the recommended method to test search results per keyword without any personalization?

Comment: Google can cater results from IP address and browser type even when in cookiless. There is no proper way that is 100% and you should expect results that vary, especially if using 'local searches' since business proximity and location is a factor. Your should gather your organic keywords using WMT and Analyitcs and these both will tell you your sites 'average' rank.

Comment: So maybe using a VPN from my target market geo location will be more similar to what normally people see compared to incognito?

Comment: Nope not exactly. Some VPNS use a block of IPS that don't have a location in the GEO databases or they use board locations.

Comment: so no better way other than the awful way I'm doing now?

Comment: Nope, use Google analyics and Webmaster Tools for realistic rankings.

Comment: Yea, I'm the king of search results for 'not provided' ;)

Comment: Not provided is only when Users are logged into Google i.e HTTPS search (around 30%-60%. You might be able to estimate your the rankings of each keyword by working out the percentage of hidden and not hidden. Another work around would be paid search via AdWords you get a report without the problem of hidden which completely contradicts their privacy terms for paying customers. Alternatively you can setup segments with Google Analyics which may help, other than that Google Search is not designed to give everyone the same search results.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it still shows up in search. Because OP mentioned VPN in the comments, answering with an international twist.

1. Try http://isearchfrom.com/

   > With I Search From you can simulate using Google Search from a different location or device, or perform a search with custom search settings. It's useful for searching Google as if you were somewhere else, as well as for SEO & SEA testing.

   > This tool was built to help people search Google from a different location or device, or using a different search language. I Search From is a free custom search tool that lets people easily do these things.

   > The tool is useful for individuals looking to change their search settings for a few search queries, as well as for advertisers and companies concerned with their website rankings on Google, whom it helps to quickly check their search engine advertising and optimization (SEA & SEO) results. For more information on search results & ad ranking see How Google Search Works. Please note that this tool is not actively maintained and result accuracy can vary.

   Based on your input country, the site will take you to a Google search URL with flags such as [`adtest`](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9055049?hl=en#adtest), `hl` etc. It also uses `adtest-useragent` which is [not documented](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adtest-useragent%22) anywhere yet seems to have an effect.
2. If you're in EU and you need to experiment a lot with other European markets, you can benefit from the EU Roaming rules. For each country you need to work with, get a cheap local SIM card with a cheap prepaid plan, where you can buy a package of ~1 GB at any time you need it, without paying for a monthly subscription.

   Because even if you're at your home abroad, your traffic will still end up routed through that country's carrier network, this is as close as it gets to being there, while not actually being there, and while having a legit local user IP address (that won't ever get detected as the server/datacenter IP etc.).

   Even if you're not in EU you can still do this, it just gets more expensive. But then again if this helps you do your job better which in return pays for it, it may be worth it.